# Why is my function looping? And not return answer

Tags: while-loop

This kata from codewar is not working!

```py
#(tribonacci([1, 2, 3], 10), [1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 20, 37, 68, 125, 230])
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    i = 0
    while len(signature) != n:
        signature.append(sum(signature[i:i + 3]))
        i += 1
    return signature
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. Perhaps you forgot to print so you didn't see the result?
For example, try this:

```py
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    i = 0
    while len(signature) != n:
        signature.append(sum(signature[i:i + 3]))
        i += 1
    return signature

print(tribonacci([1, 2, 3], 10))
```

Comment: In terminal there are no error just “ Execution timed out”

Comment: Why return don’t print signature after while end working? All the time I using return on function and take back result this time nothing (

Comment: If I write like you did there are error signature outside of function or with print signature not defined

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/556deca17c58da83c00002db/train/python  You can try yourself